# jquery ajax returning true but not display proper message?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// class exists
if($('.delete').length) {
        // add click handler
    $('.delete').click(function(){
        // ask for confirmation
        var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
        var vid     = $(this).attr('id'); 
        var row = $(this).parents('tr');  
        // do ajax request
        if(result) {
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"delete_joke.php",
                data:{id:vid,garbage:'FG9g543hfh'},
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(response){

                    // hide table row on success
                    if(response == "true") {
                        row.fadeOut();
                       $('#errors').show();
                        $('#errors').html( '<div class="message green"> Successfully deleted!<img src="http://puppetweb.ca/play/views/admin/gfx/icon-close.gif" alt="Close this item" /> </div>' ).show();

                    }else{
                       $('#errors').show();
                        $('#errors').html( '<div class="message red"> Error deleting. <img src="http://puppetweb.ca/play/views/admin/gfx/icon-close.gif" alt="Close this item" /> </div>' ).show();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    return false;
    });
}
});
```

And it works up until the part where I want to show the success, I have the php script print "true" on success and "false" on error, and if I do alert(response) it shows the word true. But it is displaying the Error deleting on success and Error deleting on error?

Any help?

Comment: please, post also the php code. Maybe the problem is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `if(response == "true")` with `if(response)` if you are sure it is returning true/false.

To check the type of data response is, try `alert(typeof response)` and see what it shows.

Edit:

Since you mention data type as JSON, make sure you return a valid response and set the content type to json in response.

If your `json` return is `{"status":true}` then you should use `if(response.status)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is scope. When the success function runs row doesn't equal anything. One of the easiest solutions is to pass back the id, exact it, use it as a selector, and hide.

If I were doing this I'd switch from json to scrip and return the JavaScript to perform. That seems more useful than true or false.